# Error: Error: C stack usage is too close to the limit

Tags: r, windows

The first thing I want to say is that yes, **I do realize there are many questions with a very similar subject line**. I promise this is unique; I have looked every single question I can find and none of them have any information that seems to help me, for various reasons.

I am working with a raster in R and whenever I try to do basically anything to this raster object, I get the error indicated by the title of the question:

`Error: C stack usage  15925776 is too close to the limit`

I am running the newest version of R (4.2.3) and RStudio (2023.03) on a Windows device. Here is my `sessionInfo()` output:

```
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] graphics  grDevices datasets  stats     utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] terra_1.7-23    moveHMM_1.8     CircStats_0.2-6 boot_1.3-28.1   MASS_7.3-58.2   maptools_1.1-5 
 [7] rgdal_1.6-5     sf_1.0-8        raster_3.6-20   sp_1.5-0        lubridate_1.8.0 forcats_0.5.2  
[13] stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.0     purrr_0.3.5     readr_2.1.3     tidyr_1.2.1     tibble_3.1.8   
[19] ggplot2_3.4.1   tidyverse_1.3.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10         lattice_0.20-45     class_7.3-21        png_0.1-7           utf8_1.2.2         
 [6] R6_2.5.1            cellranger_1.1.0    plyr_1.8.7          backports_1.4.1     reprex_2.0.2       
[11] e1071_1.7-11        httr_1.4.5          pillar_1.8.1        RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3 rlang_1.0.6        
[16] googlesheets4_1.0.1 readxl_1.4.1        rstudioapi_0.14     geosphere_1.5-14    googledrive_2.0.0  
[21] foreign_0.8-84      munsell_0.5.0       proxy_0.4-27        broom_1.0.3         compiler_4.2.3     
[26] numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 modelr_0.1.10       pkgconfig_2.0.3     tidyselect_1.2.0    codetools_0.2-19   
[31] fansi_1.0.3         crayon_1.5.2        tzdb_0.3.0          dbplyr_2.3.1        withr_2.5.0        
[36] bitops_1.0-7        grid_4.2.3          jsonlite_1.8.2      gtable_0.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.3    
[41] DBI_1.1.3           magrittr_2.0.3      units_0.8-0         scales_1.2.1        KernSmooth_2.23-20 
[46] cli_3.4.1           stringi_1.7.8       fs_1.5.2            xml2_1.3.3          ellipsis_0.3.2     
[51] generics_0.1.3      vctrs_0.5.2         tools_4.2.3         ggmap_3.0.1         glue_1.6.2         
[56] hms_1.1.2           jpeg_0.1-9          colorspace_2.0-3    gargle_1.3.0        classInt_0.4-8     
[61] rvest_1.0.3         haven_2.5.1
```

My understanding is that this error occurs when recursion goes wrong, and there are too many function calls on the stack (although please don't hesitate to correct me if I've gotten this wrong). I'm confused, though, because basically anything (even very simple raster operations) fail with this object. Examples of things that produce the C stack error include the following (`r` is the name of the raster):

```
r + 1
mean(r)
summary(r)
plot(r)
readAll(r)
terra::rast(r)
writeRaster(r, "r.tif")
```

In other words, basically anything. Here are a few things I *can* get to work:

```
> object.size(r)
14584 bytes

> print(r)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 5627, 5008, 28180016  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 30.00193, 29.99805  (x, y)
extent     : 498087.4, 648337.1, 5599179, 5767978  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : trail_road_density_formal.tif 
names      : trail_road_density_formal 
values     : 0, 36.11524  (min, max)

> str(r)
Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  ..@ file    :Formal class '.RasterFile' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ name        : chr "W:\\rasters\\trail_road_density_formal.tif"
  .. .. ..@ datanotation: chr "FLT4S"
  .. .. ..@ byteorder   : chr "little"
  .. .. ..@ nodatavalue : num -Inf
  .. .. ..@ NAchanged   : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ nbands      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ bandorder   : chr "BIL"
  .. .. ..@ offset      : int 0
  .. .. ..@ toptobottom : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ blockrows   : int 1
  .. .. ..@ blockcols   : int 5008
  .. .. ..@ driver      : chr "gdal"
  .. .. ..@ open        : logi FALSE
  ..@ data    :Formal class '.SingleLayerData' [package "raster"] with 13 slots
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ offset    : num 0
  .. .. ..@ gain      : num 1
  .. .. ..@ inmemory  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ fromdisk  : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ isfactor  : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..@ attributes: list()
  .. .. ..@ haveminmax: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..@ min       : num 0
  .. .. ..@ max       : num 36.1
  .. .. ..@ band      : int 1
  .. .. ..@ unit      : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ names     : chr "trail_road_density_formal"
  ..@ legend  :Formal class '.RasterLegend' [package "raster"] with 5 slots
  .. .. ..@ type      : chr(0) 
  .. .. ..@ values    : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ color     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ names     : logi(0) 
  .. .. ..@ colortable: logi(0) 
  ..@ title   : chr(0) 
  ..@ extent  :Formal class 'Extent' [package "raster"] with 4 slots
  .. .. ..@ xmin: num 498087
  .. .. ..@ xmax: num 648337
  .. .. ..@ ymin: num 5599179
  .. .. ..@ ymax: num 5767978
  ..@ rotated : logi FALSE
  ..@ rotation:Formal class '.Rotation' [package "raster"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ geotrans: num(0) 
  .. .. ..@ transfun:function ()  
  ..@ ncols   : int 5008
  ..@ nrows   : int 5627
  ..@ crs     :Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=utm +zone=11 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"
  .. .. ..$ comment: chr "PROJCRS[\"NAD83 / UTM zone 11N\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n  "| __truncated__
  ..@ history : list()
  ..@ z       : list()
  ..@ NA      : NULL
Warning message:
Not a validObject(): no slot of name "srs" for this object of class "RasterLayer"
```

The warning on the call to `str` briefly attracted my attention but then I realized I have other rasters that also produce this warning but do not produce the C stack error.

I realize it may be difficult because this example is not exactly reproducible, and I apologize for that. As indicated by one of the above code blocks, I can't write the raster to a file, and I received the raster as part of an R workspace (.RData) file a colleague sent me (**this may be relevant as I've worked with rasters a lot and never seen this error until now - it may have something to do with reading in an RData object rather than a .tif file on my local directory?**). In fact, whenever the C stack error comes, up, there is also a "There are 50 or more warnings" statement, and when I use ```warnings()`` to check them, it is always 50 of these:

```
W:\rasters\trail_road_density_formal.tif: No such file or directory (GDAL error 4)
```

I suppose this is where the file was stored on my colleague's device. Is there anything I can do about this other than asking them for the raw .tif file?

Most of the fixes suggested by other stackoverflow posts aren't applicable to my problem, because typically this error seems to pop up with user-written recursive code that simply has a bug. It seems like there are a few success stories from Mac and Linux OS's but I'm not sure how that transfers to Windows. Here are my attempts at implementing some of the proposed fixes, to no avail:

```
> Cstack_info()
      size    current  direction eval_depth 
  15922790      21688          1          2 
> system("ulimit -s")
[1] 127
> system("ulimit -s unlimited")
[1] 127
> r + 1
Error: C stack usage  15927824 is too close to the limit
```

Let me know if there's any more information I can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps your raster is corrupted. Instead of describing your adventure, you could put more effort into making a self-contained example, so others can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hi jay.sf, thanks. I did in fact put quite a bit of effort into it, and even apologized in my post! You may very well be right about the raster being corrupted; as I described, in my thorough efforts to make a reproducible example I realized that other rasters I have access to do not generate this issue. Nevertheless I figured there may still be some advice that folks could offer to help me out. Have a nice day!